# Why is the div element being squished when applying floats on css?

Tags: css-float

I have a couple of issues with this code:
1. The fourth `div` is being seemingly squished. Its `height` is smaller than the other divs.
2. The height of the container `div` doesn't change to 50%.  I used `wv`, but I'm not sure why % doesn't work.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drERNr

```css
.container {
 background: blue;
 width: 75%;
 height: 50vw;
}


.box {
 width: 20%;
 background: #333;
 color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: 'helvetica';
 border: 1px solid blue;
 margin: 2px;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
}

#box4 {
 width: 20%;
 background: #333;
 color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: 'helvetica';
 border: 1px solid blue;
 margin-top: 2px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <title>prac</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="one" class="box">
      <p>One</p>
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="box">
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="box">
      <p>Three</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box4">
      <p>four</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fourth element is being squashed because you `float` the first three elements to the `left`, but don't 'reset' the `float`. This can be achieved with a `clearfix`:

```
#box4:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  width: 75%;
  height: 50vw;
}

.box {
  width: 20%;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#box4:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#box4 {
  width: 20%;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <title>prac</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="one" class="box">
      <p>One</p>
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="box">
      <p>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="box">
      <p>Three</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box4">
      <p>four</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As for why you can't use `%` on the `.container`, it's because percentage-based units inherit their value from the immediate parent (and chain upwards), yet `<body>` has no fixed `height` defined. You need a calculated `height` on the parent in order for the child to be able to calculate its own `height` as a percentage.